# Style attribute in IMAGE tag is not working in all browsers

Tags: html, css, vb.net, cursor

I have a style attribute that is not working. In my code I am using an image for print. I want HAND CURSOR, so I added style attribute like the code below:

```html
<img id="btnPrint" alt="Print" imagealign="AbsBottom" onclick="winPrint()" src="../../Images/print.gif" style="cursor: hand" />
```

but this is not working in browsers other than Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html) there is compatibility table which shows hand isn't indeed supported. Use `cursor: pointer` instead of `hand` (because you really don't care about IE <5.5), as it is explained in the bottom of the page:

> In the past the hand value was
>   Microsoft's way of saying pointer; and
>   IE 5.0 and 5.5 only support hand.
>   Because it's the cursor value that's
>   used most often, most other browsers
>   have also implemented hand.
>
> Since IE 6 and 7 support pointer,
>   there's no more reason to use hand,
>   except when older IEs are part of your
>   target audience.

Comment: need an another option to use in place of window .onload(){....},  
window.document.onclick() and other functions like onkeyup(),onkeypress() on the aspx page.  
This i want on aspx page because i want to call javascript functions on onload,click or key press.So,if write them on server side on Pageload event then have to write that function on vb page and aspx page both.So i want something for aspx page only.  
Please help.